# Question about dual hypersurfaces

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Leet $F: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function which defines a hypersurface $X = \{F=0\}$. Then one can define the dual hypersurface by $F^* = 0$ where
$$
F^*(y) = y \cdot (\nabla F)^{-1}(y) - (F \circ (\nabla F)^{-1})(y)
$$
at points where $(\nabla F)^{-1}$ is well defined. The only notion of dual hypersurface $X^*$ I knew before running into this notion is the one in Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_curve

I'm struggling to understand if these two notions the same or not? Also Im interested in finding a reference for the first notion of dual hypersurface. Thank you for your help!

ps This notion came up here https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.01390.pdf page 16

Comment: This is very sloppily stated. You need equations as well as functions. What is the original hypersurface (is it $F=0$ or $F=c$? You haven't specified $F$ as homogeneous). What is the dual hypersurface? Is it $F^*=0$? I was going to ask *you* for a reference, since things are poorly stated here. Have you worked out some specific examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dual hypersurface is really a natural projective notion. In $\Bbb P^n$ (working over whatever field you want), you start with a hypersurface $X$ given by $F=0$ (with $F$ homogeneous). The dual hypersurface $X^*$ lives in $\Bbb P^{n*}$, which is the space of hyperplanes in $\Bbb P^n$, and is the locus of the tangent hyperplanes to $X$.

For any $[p]\in X$, Euler's Theorem gives us the equation
$$\sum x_i\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_i}(p) = 0$$
for the tangent hyperplane to $X$ at $[p]\in\Bbb P^n$, so $[\nabla F(p)]$ is the point on $X^*$ corresponding to $p$. (Check that everything is projectively well-defined here because, of course, $F$ is homogeneous.)

Now let's look at your formula for $F^*$. Set $y=\nabla F(x)$ (which should be a point on $X^*$). Then
$$F^*(y) = F^*(\nabla F(x)) = \nabla F(x)\cdot x - F(x).$$
There's no reason on earth this should be $0$. If $F$ is homogeneous of degree $k$ and the original hypersurface is given by $F=0$, then Euler tells us that $\nabla F(x)\cdot x = kF(x)$, so $F^*(y)$ with those hypotheses does simplify to  $(k-1)F(x)=0$.

Let's try a concrete, well-understood example. I'm still working projectively with a homogeneous $F$. Start with a quadratic hypersurface $F(x) = \frac12\sum c_i x_i^2 = 0$. Then $\nabla F = (c_1x_1,\dots,c_nx_n)$, so $y=\nabla F$ lies on $X^*$ if and only if $$G(y)=\sum \frac1{c_i}y_i^2 = 0.$$ This is all very classical. Now let's see if your formula gives this. With your formula, noting that $\nabla F$ here is the linear map with diagonal matrix $(c_i)$,
$$F^*(y) = y\cdot (\nabla F)^{-1}y - F((\nabla\ F)^{-1}(y)) = \sum \frac1{c_i}y_i^2 - \frac12 c_i(y_i/c_i)^2 = \frac12 G(y).$$

At any rate, your definition is actually is the Legendre transform of $F$. You might read the section on Geometric interpretation in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_transformation). Although I no longer have it to look at, in one of my joint papers we gave a reference to V. I. Arnold's *Singularities of systems of rays*, Russian Math Surveys **38** (1983), pp. 87-176, for a discussion of the Legendre transform. See in particular pp. 108-110.

Comment: Thank you for this very nice explanation! I edited the question to make it clearer. What I'm wondering still is when $F$ is homogeneous polynomial is it actually the case that $X^* = \{F^* = 0 \}$? One containment follows from Euler's theorem as you mentioned.

Comment: The question is what you mean by the dual hypersurface when $X$ has singularities. One notion is to take the closure of the dual coming from the nonsingular locus. What happens if you try that equation for $F(x,y)=xy=0$?